# how to generate javadoc of only one package

Tags: java, netbeans, package, javadoc

I would generate through Netbeans javadoc for only one specific package.If I press on the panel "Generate Javadocs" I obtain Javadoc of all the project.Instead I would for only one package.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `packagenames` parameter for that. Syntax:

```
javadoc [ options ] [ packagenames ] [ sourcefilenames ] [ -subpackages pkg1:pkg2:... ] [ @argfiles ]
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html):

> **packagenames** - 
>       A series of names of packages, separated by spaces, such as java.lang java.lang.reflect java.awt. You must separately specify each
>   package you want to document. Wildcards are not allowed; use
>   -subpackages for recursion. The Javadoc tool uses -sourcepath to look for these package names. See Example - Documenting One or More
>   Packages

This parameters you can apply to [Right Click on Project] > Properties > Build > Documenting you can provide additional parameters but when I needed it as you need now I just did it manually (command line), I conclude that netbeans provides the source package as already a parameter to javadoc.

Comment: But I would use netbeans.how could do that?

Comment: I just add a comment about that

Comment: what about copying code in a new project and get Javadoc from that?

Answer (score 0):

When using Netbeans 8.1:

- [Right Click on Project] > Properties > Actions
- Select Action "Generate JavaDoc"
- At "Set Properties:", specify: `subpackages=<your package(s)>`
- Click "OK"

Now for generating JavaDoc *for this project*, execute the maven `javadoc:javadoc` goal or run this goal directly from Netbeans:

- [Right Click on Project] > Generate JavaDoc

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this :

1. Place the curser on the package you want to generate the javadoc for.
2. Click on Tools -> Generate JavaDoc
3. For JavaDoc Scop, you will see your package as choice, select it
4. After specifying the ouput directory, click on Generate.